# Using patterns to modify TeXForm output

Tags: pattern-matching, latex

When I use TeXForm on a matrix I often want to replace some the output with some number of verticle and horizontal lines. Is there a way to get control over this, possibly using patterns?

As an example consider

```
TeXForm[TableForm[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, TableHeadings -> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}]]
(*Output:
\begin{array}{ccc}
      & \text{c} & \text{d} \\
  \text{a} & 1 & 2 \\
  \text{b} & 3 & 4 \\
    \end{array}
*)
```

I would like the output,

```
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
      & \text{c} & \text{d} \\ \hline
     \text{a} & 1 & 2 \\
     \text{b} & 3 & 4 \\
      \end{array}
```

Is there a way this can be automatically accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be better in the long run if you simply replaced `TableForm` by `Grid` before converting to `TeXForm`. Unlike `TableForm`, `Grid` dividers are translated correctly into $\LaTeX$:

```
TeXForm[
 Grid[
  Prepend[Transpose[
    Prepend[Transpose[
      {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
      ],
     {"a", "b"}]],
   {"", "c", "d"}], 
  Dividers -> {{None, Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic, 
     None}}]
 ]

(* =>     
//TeXForm=
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
     \text{} & \text{c} & \text{d} \\
    \hline
     \text{a} & 1 & 2 \\
     \text{b} & 3 & 4 \\
    \end{array}
*)
```

> $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
>  \text{} & \text{c} & \text{d} \\
> \hline
>  \text{a} & 1 & 2 \\
>  \text{b} & 3 & 4 \\
> \end{array}$$